# How to reset the angle of rotated view without a numpad?

Tags: interface, 3d-view, camera

I somehow rotated my view a few degrees to the side and I don't know how to reset it.

[image]

How can I reset the view?

Note: I don't have a number pad.

Comment: Didn't help, what modifies rotation of the view? I can't seem to find it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Start rotating the view *holding the mouse scroll*, then press and hold <kbd>Alt</kbd> button, while still moving the mouse. It will very quickly adjust the view as desired.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Holding <kbd>Shift</kbd> while hitting either <kbd>Num4</kbd> or <kbd>Num6</kbd> will rotate the roll of the screen. <kbd>Num4</kbd> rotates counter-clockwise while <kbd>Num6</kbd> rotates clockwise.

Answer (score 1):

Numpad keys :

<kbd>1</kbd> front view
<kbd>3</kbd> right view
<kbd>7</kbd> top view

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> back view
<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd> left view
<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>7</kbd> bottom view

<kbd>2</kbd>/<kbd>8</kbd> rotate up/down
<kbd>4</kbd>/<kbd>6</kbd> rotate left/right

<kbd>5</kbd> switch orthographic/perspective view

<kbd>+</kbd>/<kbd>-</kbd> zoom

Answer (score 1):

I found it on the bottom left: View -> Align View -> View Selected.

[image]

Comment: Refer to the question... "without a numpad?"

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is titled as "without numpad"; but in case this can help anyone else;
for resetting the "scene rotation" to zero use this:

> `Shift` + `numpad1`

If you cannot see the numpad, for example you have a laptop; then, you can use `Fn` key.

For innstance `numpad1` in my laptop is `Fn + J`; so i should use `Shift + Fn + J`