# Don't have a num pad, How would I go about changing the view?

Tags: shortcut

A lot of the shortcuts in blender uses the number pad, Where in blender can I change for example the point of view without using the shortcut.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to ***File-->User Preferences-->Input*** (or use a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> shortcut) and check the ***Emulate Numpad*** box. You can now use the normal 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0 buttons at the top of your keyboard to change camera views instead of the numpad.

Check out this answer also: [How to reset the angle of rotated view without a numpad?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/26938/how-to-reset-the-angle-of-rotated-view-without-a-numpad) It shows how to change the view without using any shortcuts.
[image]